# How to fit points to plane and project them onto that plane in C++ with Eigen

Tags: c++, linear-regression, eigen, least-squares

Sorry if this is the wrong place but I struggle a lot with the math and want to implement a circle fit in 3D using C++. I found lots of things in other programming languages but don't really understand whats going on there. Can anyone guide me on how to do that? I am not the best at math I would appreciate it if the explanation would be as simple as possible

What I tried (or tried to do lol) is as followed:

1. Get n points with x,y,z coordinates
2. fit a plane (which seems to fail)
3. project n points to 2d onto the fitted plane
4. fit a 2d circle
5. project the coordinates of the circle center back to 3d

I tried to use ordinary least squares for step 2 and also tested the results with eigens SVD which gave me completely different values compared to OSL. So I must be doing something completely wrong I guess.

Here is the code:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector4f> points;

Eigen::MatrixXf A(3,3);

Eigen::VectorXf b(3);

float a00 = 0;
float a01 = 0;
float a02 = 0;

float a10 = 0;
float a11 = 0;
float a12 = 0;

float a20 = 0;
float a21 = 0;
float a22 = 0;

float b0 = 0;
float b1 = 0;
float b2 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {

    a00 += points[i].x() * points[i].x();
    a01 += points[i].x() * points[i].y();
    a02 += points[i].x();

    a10 += points[i].x() * points[i].y();
    a11 += points[i].y() * points[i].y();
    a12 += points[i].y();

    a20 += points[i].x();
    a21 += points[i].y();
    
    b0 += points[i].x() * points[i].z();
    b1 += points[i].y() * points[i].z();
    b2 += points[i].z();
    
}

A(0,0) = a00;
A(0, 1) = a01;
A(0, 2) = a02;

A(1,0) = a10;
A(1, 1) = a11;
A(1, 2) = a12;

A(2, 0) = a20;
A(2, 1) = a21;
A(2, 2) = points.size();


b(0) = b0;
b(1) = b1;
b(2) = b2;

auto leastsquaresOSL = (A.transpose() * A).ldlt().solve(A.transpose() * b);

auto leastsquaresSVD = A.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV).solve(b);
```

EDIT: Someone suggested I edit my post and just focus on the plane fitting part. I will leave my original question up though. So here I go:

I have lots of points and want to fit a plane into it using Eigen::Vectors and Matrices. Then I would want to project the points onto the plane. I really don't know how to tackle this problem and most posts (if not all) were too complex and in Python or another language. If possible: Can anyone boil it down how to implement it in C++ using Eigen?

Comment: your data needs to be centered for the SVD to give you the correct plane, otherwise it'll give you a plane that passed through the origin.

Comment: @AhmedAEK should I divide every coefficient through the number of points I have?

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question to limit it to the plane-fitting part and ask another question regarding circle-fitting (once you solved this).

Comment: Regarding plane-fitting: Do you want to minimize the squared error in z-direction or perpendicular to the plane?

Comment: @chtz I will edit the questions as soon as I can, also to your second comment: I want to minimize perpendicular to the plane.